# Periodically cycle through multiple CardBuilder views

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

The school enterprise that I am in is studying the effects of Google Glass on driver distraction. To do so, we have been using the Stroop Effect - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stroop_effect

Up until now, we've been using a CardScrollView to allow our participants to swipe through multiple cards while using a driving simulator. The problem is that having to swipe everytime is too distracting.

Ideally, we'd like to have each view display on a set period of a few seconds or so and then switch to the next.

I've been scouring the web all day and trying so many different configurations of how this could theoretically work, but I haven't succeeded yet.

Here is the class that I have been working with most recently. I call run from the main activity function onResume().

```
package com.google.android.glass.sample.apidemo;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import com.google.android.glass.widget.CardBuilder;
import java.lang.Runnable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StroopCycle implements Runnable {
private Activity mActivity;
private ArrayList<CardBuilder> cards = new ArrayList<CardBuilder>();

public StroopCycle(Activity act){
    mActivity = act;

    cards.add(createCard(mActivity, R.drawable.one));
    cards.add(createCard(mActivity, R.drawable.two));
    cards.add(createCard(mActivity, R.drawable.three));
    cards.add(createCard(mActivity, R.drawable.four));
    cards.add(createCard(mActivity, R.drawable.five));
    cards.add(createCard(mActivity, R.drawable.six));
    cards.add(createCard(mActivity, R.drawable.seven));
    cards.add(createCard(mActivity, R.drawable.eight));
    cards.add(createCard(mActivity, R.drawable.nine));
    cards.add(createCard(mActivity, R.drawable.ten));
    cards.add(createCard(mActivity, R.drawable.eleven));
    cards.add(createCard(mActivity, R.drawable.twelve));
    cards.add(createCard(mActivity, R.drawable.thirteen));
    cards.add(createCard(mActivity, R.drawable.fourteen));
    cards.add(createCard(mActivity, R.drawable.fifteen));
    cards.add(createCard(mActivity, R.drawable.sixteen));
    cards.add(createCard(mActivity, R.drawable.seventeen));
    cards.add(createCard(mActivity, R.drawable.eighteen));
    cards.add(createCard(mActivity, R.drawable.nineteen));
    cards.add(createCard(mActivity, R.drawable.twenty));
}

@Override
public void run() {
    for(int j = 0; j < cards.size(); j++){
        mActivity.setContentView(cards.get(j).getView());
        SystemClock.sleep(1000);
        if (j == cards.size() - 1){
            j = 0;
        }
    }
}

private static CardBuilder createCard(Context context, int drawable) {
    return new CardBuilder(context, CardBuilder.Layout.TITLE)
            .addImage(drawable);
}
}
```

Any help would be SO appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use a `CardScrollView` backed up with a `CardScrollAdapter`.
You will find an example on the [official documentation website](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/card-scroller).
Then, to change the card, use either [animate(int position, Animation animationType)](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/widget/CardScrollView#animate(int,%20com.google.android.glass.widget.CardScrollView.Animation)) or [setSelection(int position)](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/widget/CardScrollView#setSelection(int))

Comment: Great idea! However, I have already tried that. The issue is that when you use animate or setSelection in a loop, only the last iteration displays.

Comment: Because you have to decouple your UI (An Activity) and your timer (A Runnable, or a Timer)

Comment: Thanks! Could you point me to some example code or something that could point me in the right direction? I'm new to Android and Google Glass development.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is basic Android development stuff. So I would recommand you to take a look at the Officila Training guides: https://developer.android.com/training/index.html